# Proving that: $\int_0^{\infty}{\dfrac{\cosh(2yt)}{(\cosh(t))^{2x}}dt}=2^{2x-2}\cdot\dfrac{\Gamma(x+y)\Gamma(x-y)}{\Gamma(2x)}$

Tags: gamma-function, beta-function

How can i prove that:

$$\int_0^{\infty}{\dfrac{\cosh(2yt)}{(\cosh(t))^{2x}}dt}=2^{2x-2}\cdot\dfrac{\Gamma(x+y)\Gamma(x-y)}{\Gamma(2x)}$$

I only can see that:
$$\dfrac{\Gamma(x+y)\Gamma(x-y)}{\Gamma(2x)}=B(x+y, x-y)$$

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $z$ in the result?

Comment: Mathematica tells me it is $\frac{2^{2x-1} \cosh(zyt) \,_2F_1[x,2 x,x+1,-1]}{x}$ when $Re[x]>0$... Based on this and user109899's comment, I would say you are a bit off on the rhs... even if the Hypergeometric function simplified to the Beta function you would still have $z$ on the rhs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting $t=\log(x)$, then $x=\frac{1}{z}$, we have:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cosh(nt)}{\cosh(t)^{2m}}\,dt = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\frac{x^n+x^{-n}}{2}}{x\left(\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2}\right)^{2m}}\,dx = 2^{2m-2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z^n+z^{-n}}{z\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2m}}\,dx $$
where the last integral can be turned into the sum of two values of the Beta function by setting $z=\tan(\arcsin\sqrt{u})=\sqrt{\frac{u}{1-u}}$.